# Un explained spikes in 2 windows nodes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing, cpu

As of this morning at 04:27 am we  have a spike of 60% CPU on both GCP nodes in GKE cluster together , with Zero usage of the system. No user is logged in. We are protected by WAF and a firewall with no DDos
activity.
It seems like an internal GKE stuff.
we do not see any process consuming High CPU.

The application is a Dot net app which had never in many years of operation shown such behaviour.

Now at 10:05 am the surge is still on.

our application is behaving very sluggishly.

I would appreciate any contribution to understand the phenomenon.

Kind regards,

Avi

I reviewed 4 windows pods CPU consumption it was Zero.
Network was also idle.